# What are the ways for client side blazor to fetch data from server?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I am experimenting with Blazor client-side for some time now and I notice that majority of different tutorials suggest client side blazor to fetch data via server side web-api.

I am not sure why is that so. Why is it not possible for razor to call a server method instead a developer having to expose same data to API. Why this extra step?

For example

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http

<button onclick=@(async () => await PrintWebApiResponse())>Print Web API Response</button>

@functions {
    private async Task PrintWebApiResponse()
    {
        var response = await Http.GetStringAsync("/api/Customer");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

Could this be rewriten to be

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http

<button onclick=@(async () => await PrintWebApiResponse())>Print Web API Response</button>

@functions {
    private async Task PrintWebApiResponse()
    {

        ServerServices.Service service = new ServerServices.Service();
        var response = service.GetCustomer();

        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

I just tried it (code was part of a partial class in Page Model) and it works perfectly fine. Am i missing a point here? Why is it recommended to expose this method over API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure how you've got your test code setup but it's physically not possible to do what you're implying. Blazor WebAssembly runs entirely on the client, the whole app is bootstrapped and run there. It has no active connection to the server to be able to access a server-side service. This is why you need to make calls to the server using Web APIs.

Blazor WebAssembly is still a client-side single-page application framework, like Angular or Vue, it just happens to use C#.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that the solution is configured so the app  uses an ASP.NET Core backend i e. ASP.NET Core hosted. Could that option make this code actually run?

Comment: It would still need to make an HTTP call from the client to the API, even when using the hosted project.

Comment: When i read this carefully on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1  After selecting the Blazor WebAssembly App template, you have the option of configuring the app to use an ASP.NET Core backend by selecting the ASP.NET Core hosted check box (dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted). The ASP.NET Core app serves the Blazor app to clients. The Blazor WebAssembly app can interact with the server over the network using web API calls or SignalR. This last part "API calls OR SignalR" makes me thing if I use direct method call would app use SignalR for it?

Comment: No that's not the case. You can use SignalR but you have to set that up the same as you would for a JavaScript-based client.

Comment: If you are right, then the only thing left is that this is not a blazor web assembly soltution, but a blazor server solution which i am 99.9% sure it is not. I am confused. Just to rule out that possibility what is the best way to spot a difference between web assembly and server blazor?

Comment: Is the code available somewhere I can take a look? You can tell if you are using a Blazor Server project by checking the csproj file. A Blazor Server project targets netcoreapp3.1 (or 3 depending on how old your code is). A Blazor WebAssembly app targets netstandard2.1 (or 2).

Comment: Versions are correct as you suggested, but I noticed that inside of a service method I have used dummy data that were hardcoded, ie didn't have any server interaction. I believe this caused this method call do be successfully executed. I added more specific call that interacts with server and I got an error failed to Fetch.

Comment: Cool, could you mark my answer as correct in case any others have the same issue.